# Your session has expired. Please log in, Xcode 8.2 giving this error while adding account

Tags: xcode

apple developer id is not able to add in xcode 8.2, it gives error like below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging in to your account like the error suggests?

Comment: i tried same account in ITune connect & it works normal. But not able to add in xcode

Comment: What about at [developer.apple.com](//developer.apple.com)?

Comment: i just check and it works in developer.apple.com too, just problem while adding xcode

Comment: Did you try logging into Xcode again after logging in elsewhere?

Comment: yes tried each and every case, this is something new that i face

Comment: I googled the error; it seems this is a that happens rarely to some users.  Some people said it worked after they enabled Two Factor Authentication for their Apple ID; if that doesn't work or you don't want to do that, your best bet is to contact Apple Developer Support.

Comment: I am also experiencing same issue. 
@ajay_nasa   did you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: This is happening again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be on the Apple's side and is not related to Two-Factor Authentication. I contacted the Apple Developer Support by filling in this form:

https://developer.apple.com/contact/apple-id/

They fixed the issue for my account by next day. I got this answer by email:

> We believe this issue has been resolved. I encourage you to try to sign in to Xcode later on today. If you are still encountering this specific issue, please send us a screenshot of the error and steps to reproduce the issue.

Don't hesitate to contact the support team.

Comment: Thank you to do not wasting my time with enabling 2FA :)

Answer (score 18):

[Amit Srivastava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4189597/amit-srivastava) give this detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178121/3360187)

Apple forcing developers to use two factors password security and follow these steps to enable it

**On your apple device with iOS 9+**

1. Go to Settings > iCloud > tap your Apple ID
2. Password & Security
3. Turn on Two-Factor Authentication

**On your Mac Pro with OS X El Capitan or later**

1. Go to Apple () menu > System Preferences > iCloud > Account Details
2. Click Security
3. Turn on Two-Factor Authentication

If you already use two-step verification, turn it off, then turn on two-factor authentication

Comment: I called apple support, they are saying two factor auth doesn't have any relation with the issue. Does this really work ?

Comment: It says that two-step verification is not available for my account.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like Apple is forcing developers to use 2 factors password security. i've fixed the issue by applying for 2 factors security and now its working

Comment: I don't think it's *intentional*; they'd have a better error message if that was the case.  Most likely, enabling 2FA resets something in the login system, working around a glitch.

Comment: This worked for me. However I only had to do it for one of my accounts, the other still works fine without it. Very odd behavior.

Comment: Worked for me too. Makes me really angry though.

Comment: There is no any official post from Apple about this. It looks like an error on Apple side.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasted a lot of time on this. This is unacceptable from Apple!! They should at least show an appropriate error message!

Comment: Apple doesn't care about developers.

Comment: The worst thing is that I've they required a password change before, and now the account is blocked for 3 days before allowing two step authorisation!

Answer (score 0):

Apple has fixed the issue (at least for the moment). No need for the suggested two factor authentication workaround.

Comment: are you sure?  I am on xCode 8.3.3 and I was getting issues until I turned OFF and then turned ON two-factor authentication at https://appleid.apple.com/

Comment: The answer was regarding Xcode 8.2 in december 2016 hence the "at least for the moment" comment.