# Xcode 8.1 says 'try signing in again or contact apple support to resolve account access issue' what should I do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, apple-id

I'm using a macbook pro, OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6
Every time I try to add my apple id into it It says 
**'try signing in again or contact apple developer support to resolve the account access issue'** but same id successfully login on web. Most important my other ids working perfect in Xcode

**What I've already done**

1. Remove all account and try to login again
2. Quit Xcode and restart Mac Pro
3. Update all Certificates Keychain Access
4. Delete all Expire Certificates from Keychain Access

Now what should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Added two factor authentication to Apple ID its worked for me.

You can follow the steps below to turn on two-factor authentication.

**On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch with iOS 9 or later:**

Go to Settings > iCloud > tap your Apple ID.

Tap Password & Security.

Tap Turn on Two-Factor Authentication.

**On your Mac with OS X El Capitan or later:**

Go to Apple () menu > System Preferences > iCloud > Account Details.

Click Security.

Click Turn on Two-Factor Authentication.

If you already use two-step verification, turn it off, then turn on two-factor authentication.

[Read more](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204915)

Comment: this works for me.  verified.